# Titanium Studio or Eclipse: How to save workbench state?

Tags: eclipse, titanium, appcelerator, workbench

TiStudio 3.2 (based on Eclipse):

Is there a option to save current state of workbench? I mean: opened editor windows, layout, etc.

Per project would be fine.

Everytime I switch projects, those states are lost and I cannot see any option where to set them.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

install mylyn eclipse plugin.
It provides a task focused workflow that remembers contexts of the workbench for every task.
Really good way of changing contexts.

Take a look at this tuto: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mylyn/article.html